# How to disable the event ghost in ZK Calendar?

Tags: zk, zul, zk-calendar

I'm using **ZK CE-9.0.0** & **[zk-calendar-2.1.5 source code](https://www.zkoss.org/download/zkcalendar)**.

I'm handling the event `onEventCreate` of `calendars`, to create new events in the calendar.
Whenever I'm doing so, an event ghost/dragging ghost is also created. Please refer to the below screenshot.

[image]

I want to get rid of this event ghost. I achieve this by executing the following piece of code placed inside the event handling method:

```
@Listen("onEventCreate = #calendars")
public void createEvent(CalendarsEvent event) {
     event.clearGhost();
}
```

Although this code works, the event ghost still appears for half a second.
While I want that this event ghost doesn't appear on screen at all.

How can I achieve the same?

Thanks,

RAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution would be to use a style to hide the ghost event.

```
<style>
    .z-calendars-evt-ghost{
        opacity: 0;
    }
</style>
```

if you want to apply this to a specific component, you can use a sclass on the calendars component and include it in the style declaration:

```
<style>
    .no-ghost .z-calendars-evt-ghost{
        opacity: 0;
    }
</style>

<div sclass="no-ghost" >
    <calendars id="calendars"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. It's really helpful. I used the 2nd solution as I wanted to show/hide this event ghost based on certain conditions. So removing/adding the sclass "no-ghost" dynamically to the parent div of the calendars component, based on the conditions, did the trick.